# returning a complete data.frame from a function in R

Tags: r

i want to store additional information on top of a data.frame and return it from a function. as you can see - the additional data disappears.
example :

```
> d<-data.frame(N1=c(1,2,3),N2=(LETTERS[1:3]))
> d
  N1 N2
1  1  A
2  2  B
3  3  C
> d.x = 3
> d
  N1 N2
1  1  A
2  2  B
3  3  C
> d.x
[1] 3
> foo1 <- function() {
+ d<-data.frame(N1=c(1,2,3),N2=(LETTERS[1:3]))
+ d.x=3
+ return(d)
+ }
> 
> d1<-foo1()
> d1
  N1 N2
1  1  A
2  2  B
3  3  C
> d1.x
Error: object 'd1.x' not found
```

i looked into `assign` but since the data.frame is created inside the function and being returned i assume that it's not relevant here.
Thanks.

Comment: This makes little sense. How exactly is the value 3 supposed to be added "on top of" the data frame d? A new row? An attribute?

Comment: i know what you mean but it works and this is what i need. the only problem is that when i return the data.frame from a function the additional data is not returned. i just need to return a data structure containing both data rows and metadata.

Comment: you need a minimal introduction to R. d.x is a separate object, in no way related to x. if you want to have a column in d called x then you refer to it as d$x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments suggest you want to create an attribute (the usual way to attach "metadata" to objects in R) named "d.3" and use foo1 to set that attribute for a dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(N1=c(1,2,3),N2=(LETTERS[1:3]))
foo1 <- function(d, attrib) {
   attr(d, "d.x") <- attrib
  return(d)
  }
d <- foo1(d, 3)  # need to assign value to 'd' since function results are not "global"
d    # note that the default print method for dataframes does not show the attributes
#---------
  N1 N2
1  1  A
2  2  B
3  3  C
#-----
 attributes(d)
#-----

$names
[1] "N1" "N2"

$row.names
[1] 1 2 3

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$d.x
[1] 3
```

See `?attr` and `?attributes` for more specifics. There is also a `comments` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
d.x=3
```

to this:

```
d$x=3
```

Comment: While the answer is correct, explaining who the change is needed would be helpful.

Comment: This may be what the OP is after, but we should note that it will create an entire column of 3's, rather than a single value.